# Scala extending while loops to do-until expressions

Tags: scala

I'm trying to do some experiment with Scala. I'd like to repeat this experiment (randomized) until the expected result comes out and get that result. If I do this with either while or do-while loop, then I need to write (suppose 'body' represents the experiment and 'cond' indicates if it's expected):

```
do {
  val result = body
} while(!cond(result))
```

It does not work, however, since the last condition cannot refer to local variables from the loop body. We need to modify this control abstraction a little bit like this:

```
def repeat[A](body: => A)(cond: A => Boolean): A = {
  val result = body
  if (cond(result)) result else repeat(body)(cond)
}
```

It works somehow but is not perfect for me since I need to call this method by passing two parameters, e.g.:

```
val result = repeat(body)(a => ...)
```

I'm wondering whether there is a more efficient and natural way to do this so that it looks more like a built-in structure:

```
val result = do { body } until (a => ...)
```

One excellent solution for body *without a return value* is found in this post: [How Does One Make Scala Control Abstraction in Repeat Until?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036058/how-does-one-make-scala-control-abstraction-in-repeat-until), the last one-liner answer. Its `body` part in that answer does not return a value, so the `until` can be a method of the new `AnyRef` object, but that trick does not apply here, since we want to return `A` rather than `AnyRef`. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Why you don't like recursion in this code? It's tail recursion so stack will not grow.

Comment: I'm not quite confident about the tail recursion optimization. I once wrote a BFS algorithm using that technique, it still stack overflows. I may post another question on that. Anyway, this is just a minor problem, I do want to see how I can make my code more native-looking.

Comment: If you get a stackoverflow it's not tail recursive. You can tell the compiler, that a method should be tail recursive by adding `@annotation.tailrec`. If it is not, the compiler will fail.

Comment: Thanks, I just solved the problem. I defined the tail-recursive function in an abstract class without a final keyword. The compiler doesn't do any optimization so it overflows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a minor modification you can turn your current approach in a kind of mini fluent API, which results in a syntax that is close to what you want:

```
class run[A](body: => A) {
  def until(cond: A => Boolean): A = {
    val result = body
    if (cond(result)) result else until(cond)
  }
}
object run {
  def apply[A](body: => A) = new run(body)
}
```

Since `do` is a reserved word, we have to go with `run`. The result would now look like this:

```
run {
  // body with a result type A
} until (a => ...)
```

**Edit:**

I just realized that I almost reinvented what was already proposed in the linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036058/how-does-one-make-scala-control-abstraction-in-repeat-until). One possibility to extend that approach to return a type `A` instead of `Unit` would be:

```
def repeat[A](body: => A) = new {
  def until(condition: A => Boolean): A = {
    var a = body
    while (!condition(a)) { a = body }
    a     
  }   
}
```

Comment: @Yang: Wasn't there a comment from you? This was my answer: Why do you want to return `A` from `repeat` itself? Since you call `until` only this return type is relevant. I just tested something like: `val result = repeat { Random.nextInt(10) } until (_ == 0)`.

Comment: Yes, I added that comment, but I soon realized the true meaning of the until function. In the syntax `repeat {...} until ()`, `until` is just a function, so the return should be from `until` instead of `repeat`. Thanks again, this is very interesting to me.

Comment: You're welcome! I think than it is also good to keep the first, more verbose version in my answer, since in this version it is (maybe) more clear that `until` is just a member function returning an `A`.

Answer (score 6):

You're mixing programming styles and getting in trouble because of it.

Your loop is only good for heating up your processor unless you do some sort of side effect within it.

```
do {
  val result = bodyThatPrintsOrSomething
} until (!cond(result))
```

So, if you're going with side-effecting code, just put the condition into a var:

```
var result: Whatever = _
do {
  result = bodyThatPrintsOrSomething
} until (!cond(result))
```

or the equivalent:

```
var result = bodyThatPrintsOrSomething
while (!cond(result)) result = bodyThatPrintsOrSomething
```

Alternatively, if you take a functional approach, you're going to have to return the result of the computation anyway.  Then use something like:

```
Iterator.continually{ bodyThatGivesAResult }.takeWhile(cond)
```

(there is a known annoyance of `Iterator` not doing a great job at taking all the good ones plus the first bad one in a list).

Or you can use your `repeat` method, which is tail-recursive.  If you don't trust that it is, check the bytecode (with `javap -c`), add the `@annotation.tailrec` annotation so the compiler will throw an error if it is not tail-recursive, or write it as a while loop using the `var` method:

```
def repeat[A](body: => A)(cond: A => Boolean): A = {
  var a = body
  while (cond(a)) { a = body }
  a
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know the loop is imperative so come up with something more functional like the repeat function. It works for me, but I want it more native-looking like the one in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036058/how-does-one-make-scala-control-abstraction-in-repeat-until

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Iterator approach and the warning that the whole construction relies an side effects in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Just to document a derivative of the suggestions made earlier, I went with a tail-recursive implementation of `repeat { ... } until(...)` that also included a limit to the number of iterations:

```
def repeat[A](body: => A) = new {
  def until(condition: A => Boolean, attempts: Int = 10): Option[A] = {
    if (attempts <= 0) None
    else {
      val a = body
      if (condition(a)) Some(a)
      else until(condition, attempts - 1)
    }
  }
}
```

This allows the loop to bail out after `attempts` executions of the body:

```
scala> import java.util.Random
import java.util.Random

scala> val r = new Random()
r: java.util.Random = java.util.Random@cb51256

scala> repeat { r.nextInt(100) } until(_ > 90, 4)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(98)

scala> repeat { r.nextInt(100) } until(_ > 90, 4)
res1: Option[Int] = Some(98)

scala> repeat { r.nextInt(100) } until(_ > 90, 4)
res2: Option[Int] = None

scala> repeat { r.nextInt(100) } until(_ > 90, 4)
res3: Option[Int] = None

scala> repeat { r.nextInt(100) } until(_ > 90, 4)
res4: Option[Int] = Some(94)
```